# Converting the varchar value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to count the values that are same in both the tables and seem to be running into an error on the first line.

```
select 
    count(substring(c.source_code, 3, 4)) comb,  ---->Error
    count(os.CompanyCode) comcode 
from 
    combined c
inner join 
    Completes os on os.companycode = substring(c.source_code,3,4)
where 
    os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
    and c.return_year = 2017
```

Error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SH' to data type int

Dataset:

```
Combined.sourcecode                      Completes.companycode
-------------------                      ---------------------
  01582365                                 5823  
  14785698                                 7856
  45879652                                 8796
  87459633                                 4596 
  14563344                                 5633
```

Results requested:

```
 comb                              comcode
 ------------------------------------------
   5                                 5
```

Comment: And it's not the JOIN condition?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  The line you have highlighted is not causing this error.

Comment: @Gordon, provided.

Comment: @JakeWagner you expect 5 and 5 as output?

Comment: @picklerick Yes. The number of values existing in both.

Comment: Note that the line numbers given in SQL Server error messages tell you "the error occurred in the statement (no matter how many lines it covers) that started *here*"

Comment: @JakeWagner check my answer if fits your needs

Comment: @JakeWagner . . . An error on "SH" is definitely not coming from the values you have provided.   Your sample data doesn't illustrate the question.

Comment: @JakeWagner the error would make sense if `Completes.Companycode` is an *integer* but `substring(c.source_code,3,4)` returned `SH`. The server tries to convert that string into an integer in order to compare the values, hence the error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . The only odd thing about that is that I would expect the substring to have four characters.

Answer (score 1):

if ouy need the number of items not null from this you can use :

```
select sum(case when c.source_code is not null then 1 else 0 end) combCount,  
sum(case when os.CompanyCode is not null then 1 else 0 end) comcodeCount,
substring(c.source_code,3,4) comb,  
os.CompanyCode as comcode  
from combined c
inner join Completes os on os.companycode = substring(c.source_code,3,4)
where os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
and c.return_year = 2017
group by substring(c.source_code,3,4),os.CompanyCode
```

or if you just need the number of records:

```
select count(*) as records, substring(c.source_code,3,4) comb,  
os.CompanyCode as comcode 
from combined c
inner join Completes os on os.companycode = substring(c.source_code,3,4)
where os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
and c.return_year = 2017
group by substring(c.source_code,3,4),os.CompanyCode
```

Answer (score 1):

I think CompanyCode or Source_code has alphanumeric data. Because of that you get error message.

I have updated your script, it should be ok:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(SUBSTRING(c.source_code, 3, 4)) comb
   ,COUNT(os.CompanyCode) comcode
FROM combined c
INNER JOIN Completes os
    ON CAST(os.companycode AS VARCHAR(100)) = CAST(SUBSTRING(c.source_code, 3, 4) AS VARCHAR(100))
WHERE os.ReturnYearFiled = 2017
AND c.return_year = 2017
```

Also, if you want to check which values are alphanumeric you can use `ISNUMERIC` :

```
SELECT * FROM combined WHERE IsNumeric(source_code)=0
SELECT * FROM Completes WHERE IsNumeric(source_code)=0
```